# Change map's palette in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

how do I change the color palette of my map to one where the lowest value is not similar to white? For example, vidris or some other package. I have tried adding it to my map based on examples but I have failed.

```
ggplot(all) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill=pct_hisp), colour = "grey95", size = 0.01) + 
  scale_fill_distiller(name = "% Hispanic", palette = "Reds", direction = 1, 
                       na.value = "grey96") + theme_void() + 
  geom_polygon( data=MainStates, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group),
                  color="white", fill = NA, size = 0.05)
```

Thank you!!

[Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwU6Z.png)

Comment: Well, what colors do you want? The default pallets are pulled from [colorbrewer](https://colorbrewer2.org/).  The color scheme is set by the `palette=` argument.

Comment: Colors from vidris or other packages

Comment: `ggplot2` has a function called `scale_fill_viridis_c` to use the viridis color scheme. https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_viridis.html